# Python - import gtk in headless CentOS 6, causing the application execution failure

Tags: python, gtk, centos, pygtk, x11

I am using import gtk , gobject to run a multi-thread server (but actually i do not use GUI)

- in my local desktop it works perfect.
- But now i am trying to put it in server, and there its failing as below:

I am using cloud CentOS server:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /var/tmp/protocol/server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/protocol/server.py", line 53, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

code:

```
import gtk
import object

class server(object):

  def listener(self, sock, *args):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    gobject.io_add_watch(conn, gobject.IO_IN, self.handler)
    return True

  def handler(self, conn, *args):
    line = conn.recv(4096)
    ...

  def __init__(self):
    print "starting.."

  def run(self):
    """ Socket prepare """
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.bind(('', 7007))
    self.sock.listen(1)
    print "Listening..."
    gobject.io_add_watch(self.sock, gobject.IO_IN, self.listener)
    gtk.main() # import to let it run as 24/7

if __name__=='__main__':
    s=server()
    s.run()
```

**EDIT:** Tried this but not working

```
  mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
  s=server()
  s.run()
  mainloop.run()
```

Find where the problem is:

$ python -m trace --trace server.py

```
__init__.py(634):         if self.lock:
__init__.py(635):             self.lock.release()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: release
threading.py(137):         if self.__owner != _get_ident():
threading.py(139):         self.__count = count = self.__count - 1
threading.py(140):         if not count:
threading.py(141):             self.__owner = None
threading.py(142):             self.__block.release()
threading.py(144):                 self._note("%s.release(): final release", self)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: _note
threading.py(65):             if self.__verbose:
__init__.py(682):         return rv
__init__.py(1217):             for hdlr in c.handlers:
__init__.py(1221):             if not c.propagate:
__init__.py(1224):                 c = c.parent
__init__.py(1216):         while c:
__init__.py(1225):         if (found == 0) and raiseExceptions and not self.manager.emittedNoHandlerWarning:
server.py(562):       return False
```

Comment: gtk is a GUI toolkit, not really suitable for building servers. There are tons of more appropriate packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at the glib module and in particular help(glib.MainLoop).  Under the covers gtk uses glib for most things; you can use gobject, ios, etc.  But glib does not have graphical dependencies.

Comment: You mean: `loop = gobject.MainLoop() gobject.threads_init() context = loop.get_context() while 1:
        # Handle commands here
        ...
        context.iteration(True)`  ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean: `self.timer = gobject.timeout_add(time_in_ms, self.remote.keepalive)`
 ?

Comment: Your constructor for the main loop looks correct without having run the code

Comment: Not working still. getting frozen in the `def handler(self, conn, *args):`